# Fetch all records and join a column with grouped data in Mongoose (MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two Mongo collections, Users and Activities. Each activity has a `createdAt` field (type Date) along with a `hoursWorked` (type Number) field and a `user` reference. Each user just has an `id` and `name` field (for simplicity). I would like to fetch a list of activities and join the user's name, but I would also like to join the total number of `hoursWorked` for that particular day and user with respect to each row.

Here is some example input data and expected results:

**Activities Collection**

| createdAt | hoursWorked | user |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "2021-01-01" | 2 | a1 |
| "2021-01-01" | 1 | a1 |
| "2021-01-02" | 3 | a1 |
| "2021-01-02" | 3 | a1 |
| "2021-01-01" | 1 | b2 |
| "2021-01-01" | 1 | b2 |
| "2021-01-02" | 2 | b2 |

**Users Collection**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | Alfred |
| b2 | Brenda |

---

**Expected Output**

| createdAt | hoursWorked | name | totalHoursForDay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "2021-01-01" | 2 | Alfred | 3 |
| "2021-01-01" | 1 | Alfred | 3 |
| "2021-01-02" | 3 | Alfred | 6 |
| "2021-01-02" | 3 | Alfred | 6 |
| "2021-01-01" | 1 | Brenda | 2 |
| "2021-01-01" | 1 | Brenda | 2 |
| "2021-01-02" | 5 | Brenda | 5 |

Joining the users is easy, but I'm struggling to figure out how to aggregate by user and date and then join that all in. I'm currently planning to just fetch the activities, then loop through in my Node Express application to aggregate the hours in a JavaScript object then join it that way, but I'm wondering if anyone has more efficient ways to do this with a Mongoose query? Here's the code I have so far...pretty basic for now.

```
const activities = await Activity
    .find({}, null, { sort: { createdAt: 1 } })
    .populate("user", "name").exec();
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that in a single query. just do it manually using `map`.
make an empty object where keys are the days and values are the totalHours worked in that day.

```
const totalHoursForEachDay = {};
activities.forEach(AC=>{
  if (totalHoursForEachDay[AC.createdAt]) // if it has that day{
    totalHoursForEachDay += AC.hoursWorked;
    return;
} 
// 
 totalHoursForEachDay[AC.createdAt] = AC.hoursWorked; 
});
```

then map both to each other

```
const new_activites = activities.map(AC=>{
    return {...AC , totalHours: totalHoursForEachDay[AC.createdAt]}

});
```

## Another answer

would be to aggregate the totalHours for each day first.
and then do the second step in the first answer

Comment: Thank you, this was my idea as well. And you're suggesting to do this all server-side with Node, right?